# Python List Сложение Умножение

Tags: python, list

Есть список в котором 7 рандомных чисел [list()].

Надо посчитать сумму первых четерех элементов и умножение последних трех.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наш список состоит из 7 чисел. По индексам первые 4 элемента - 0, 1, 2, 3 - а последние 3 элемента - 4, 5, 6.
Пройдём циклом по этим индексам и посчитаем сумму (с помощью переменной `summa`) и произведение (с помощью переменной `result`).

```
lst = [2, 6, 3, 4, 9, 6, 5]
summa = 0
result = 1
for index in range(4):
    summa += lst[index]
for index in range(4, 7):
    result *= lst[index]
print(f'Сумма первых четырех чисел: {summa}. Произведение последних трех чисел: {result}.')
```

Comment: Я уже сам решил, но спасибо. Твой код работает :)